# Why is this just playing a quarter of a sine wave in pyaudio?

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to create a sine wave with pyaudio, and it seems like this code should create an entire waveform, repeated 1000 times:

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
f = 440.0        # sine frequency, Hz, may be float
duration = 1/f   # in seconds, may be float

def sine_sampler(length, frequency, sampling_rate=44100):
    """Generate sine samples of volume 1"""
    sine_samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(length) * frequency / sampling_rate))
    return sine_samples.astype(np.float32)

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=1, rate=fs, output=True)

sound = sine_sampler(duration * fs, f)
print(sound)
for i in range(1000):
    stream.write(sound)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

When I print the sound after generating it, I get the expected behavior: an array that cycles up and down, as one cycle of a sine wave:

```
[ 0.          0.06264833  0.12505053  0.18696144  0.24813785  0.30833942
  0.3673296   0.42487666  0.48075455  0.53474367  0.586632    0.6362156
  0.6832998   0.72769946  0.76924026  0.807759    0.84310424  0.87513727
  0.9037321   0.92877656  0.9501721   0.9678348   0.98169506  0.9916987
  0.9978062   0.9999937   0.99825245  0.9925895   0.983027    0.9696024
  0.9523687   0.9313933   0.90675884  0.87856203  0.84691364  0.811938
  0.77377254  0.73256713  0.6884838   0.64169556  0.5923863   0.5407498
  0.4869888   0.43131465  0.37394598  0.3151082   0.25503248  0.19395483
  0.13211517  0.06975647  0.00712373 -0.055537   -0.11797953 -0.17995858
 -0.24123062 -0.30155495 -0.36069456 -0.41841713 -0.47449586 -0.5287105
 -0.5808479  -0.63070345 -0.67808115 -0.7227949  -0.76466894 -0.8035389
 -0.83925205 -0.87166804 -0.90065956 -0.92611265 -0.94792736 -0.96601796
 -0.9803134  -0.9907575  -0.99730927 -0.9999429  -0.9986481  -0.99342996
 -0.98430896 -0.9713209  -0.9545169  -0.9339628  -0.90973955 -0.8819423
 -0.85068005 -0.81607586 -0.77826554 -0.7373977  -0.6936328  -0.6471429
 -0.59811056 -0.54672843 -0.4931984  -0.43773076 -0.3805434  -0.32186103
 -0.2619142  -0.20093836 -0.1391731  -0.07686108 -0.0142471 ]
```

However, the resulting sine wave is only the first quarter of a sine wave, repeated again and again, as seen in this screenshot from Audacity:

[image]

It's only when I change `duration` to `4/f`, getting four cycles, that it actually produces a smooth, complete sine wave.

[image]

Experiments with other durations support this same pattern of only playing part of the sound. Why is only the first fourth of each cycle being played?

Comment: should be `sine_samples.astype(np.float32).tostring()` see this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675731/howto-stream-numpy-array-into-pyaudio-stream)

Comment: @fdcpp Thanks! That fixed it.