# Can I do recognition from numpy array in python SpeechRecognition?

Tags: numpy, audio, speech-recognition, wav, audio-recording

I'm recording a numpy array `dt` and then writing it in .wav by code like this:

```
dt = np.int16(dt/np.max(np.abs(dt)) * 32767)
scipy.io.wavfile.write("tmp.wav", samplerate, dt)
```

after that I read it and recognize by code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile("tmp.wav") as source:
    audio_text = r.listen(source)
    return r.recognize_google(audio_text, language = lang)
```

Can I do recognition from numpy array without using wav? Cuz it takes excess time

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the module you are using, and according to [its documentation](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#audiofilefilename_or_fileobject-unionstr-ioiobase---audiofile), you can pass any file-like object to `AudioFile()`. File-like objects are objects that support read and write operations.

You should be able to stick the byte representation of the wav file into a [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) object, which supports these operations, and pass that into your speech recognition module. [`scipy.io.wavfile.write()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) supports writing to such file-like objects.

I don't have the package or any WAV files to test it, but let me know if something like this works:

```
wav_bytes = io.BytesIO()
scipy.io.wavfile.write(wav_bytes, samplerate, dt)
with sr.AudioFile(wav_bytes) as source:
    ...
```

Comment: I know that I should transform numpy array to some object for SpeechRecognition but I donna how to it, whats way, which functions

Comment: Well I‘m not going to write the code for you. Have you tried anything of what I suggested, using the `BytesIO`?

Comment: It doesn't work. Scipy works only with ndarry, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675731/howto-stream-numpy-array-into-pyaudio-stream) there is the answer how to play numpy array in pyaudio. New question is how to use PyAudio stream in SpeechRecognition methods

Comment: I understand what you want to do. Numpy array -> SpeechRecognition method. What I'm telling you is you need to use a file-like object, such as `BytesIO` for that. This doesn't actually write any files, it's all in memory. The answer you linked does a similar thing; they also use file-like objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an audio data object first with AudioData, this is the source that the recognizer needs as a file-like object:

```
import io
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import speech_recognition

byte_io = io.BytesIO(bytes())
write(byte_io, sr, audio_array)
result_bytes = byte_io.read()

audio_data = speech_recognition.AudioData(result_bytes, sr, 2)
r = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
```

audio_array is a 1-D numpy.ndarray with int16 values and sr is the sampling rate.